# Accessing lists with sequential variable names

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested-lists

I am trying to access data from multiple lists with sequential variable name for further mathematical operations.

For example,

```
data_1 = [1, 2, 3, ... n]
data_2 = [4, 5, 6, ... n]
''
''
data_N = [n, n, n, ... n]

data_vector = []

for i in range(n):
    data = 'data_' + str(i)
    data_vector.append(data)
```

This gives me `data_vector = ['data_1', 'data_2', ... 'data_N']` as names only but not the values from the listed variables.

I want to get `data_vector = [[1, 2, 3, ... n], [3, 4, 5, ... n], ... [n, n, n, ... n]]`.

I have more than 20 data list and writing each should not be the efficient way.

Comment: How do you get `Data_1`, ... in the first place?

Comment: You may consider defining those lists as values in a dictionary/hashmap instead.

Comment: Its being extracted from raw data set

Comment: Don't do that. Instead of a variable called `Data_1` the standard Python approach is to use a `dict` called `Data` and do `Data["1"] =[1,2,3.....n]`.

Comment: How does this raw data set look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can access globals() for this:

```
for i in range (n):
    data = 'Data_'+str(i)
    data_vector.append(globals()[data])
```

However, you would better save your lists in a dictionary like below:

```
d = {'Data_1';[1,2,3...n], 'Data_2':[2,4,6,...n]}
```

and call each list with:

```
d['Data_' + str(i)]
```

Comment: One should not use global variables, particularly, don't use `globals()`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
data_dict = {'data1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
             'data2':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
             'data3':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
             }

data_vec = []

for i in data_dict.keys():
    data_vec.append(data_dict[i])
```

that should work